# Make A Servlet Project with derby database standalone

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, derby

i have developed a web application using Java Servlet technologies using Derby database with help of NetBeans IDE , now whenever i want to run that application i have to run it with the help of NeatBeans, and i want deploy the web application and make it standalone like it should be operational without netbeans too,please help me,please
i have already tried running glassfish bat file but that does not run the database .

Comment: Perhaps you are using the Derby Network Server configuration and your Network Server is not running. You can start the Network Server by hand, or you can convert your application to a Derby Embedded configuration. You can learn more about this here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/

Comment: i did run the network server by running startserv.bat file which is present in the glassfish directory